# open cv2 converting color image to grayscale

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to convert color image to gray scale using Opencv2 library with python 3.7 using XAMPP server and the result is on the web is:

```
   no image --> -->


error   Python 3.7.0: C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Fri Aug 24 21:58:51 2018
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 C:\xampp\htdocs\cv2\rgbtogray.py in <module>()
     17         print ("no image")
     18 
=>   19 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     20 cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
     21 cv2.waitKey(0)
gray undefined, cv2 = <module 'cv2' from 'C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Lo...on37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\cv2.cp37-win32.pyd'>, cv2.cvtColor = <built-in function cvtColor>, img = None, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY = 6
error: OpenCV(3.4.2) d:\build\opencv\opencv-3.4.2\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:253: error: (-215:Assertion failed) VScn::contains(scn) && VDcn::contains(dcn) && VDepth::contains(depth) in function 'cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper' 
      args = ("OpenCV(3.4.2) d:\\build\\opencv\\opencv-3.4.2\\modul...et<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper'\n",)
```

here is the code i executed using xampp

```
#!C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

print('Content-type: text/html\r\n')
print('\r\n')

import cgitb
import cv2
import numpy as np

cgitb.enable()


img = cv2.imread('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\cv2\\color.png')
if img is None:
    print ("no image")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[here is the image i want to convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av3AB.png)

Comment: firstly did you check if `img` is valid and not `None`, secondly what is the format of the image? is it really BGR or is it RGB? does it have an alpha channel as this would make it BGRA or RGBA. You need to determine this

Comment: `imshow`/`waitkey` don't really make sense on server side -- even if there was a GUI running, there probably won't be anyone there to look at it. What do you actually expect this script to do?

Comment: BGR and RGB is the same thing with python

Comment: I am only trying now to apply opecv2 image processing things to develop image editor app working on the web later

Comment: @EdChum OP is calling `imread` with the second parameter unspecified, meaning it loads any kind of image as BGR, doing necessary conversions.

Comment: I'd suggest adding an `exit()` right after `print("no image")`, since right now, you still try to run the rest of the script even after you know you failed to load an image. Now, question is, why is it failing to load that image... can you load that image file from an interactive interpreter? Can your script `open` it as a regular file and read the whole thing into memory?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `\` and `x` in your path is acting as an escape character, and Python thinks it's loading a hex value.

You could simply add `r` before your file path to convert it to a raw string like this:

```
   img = cv2.imread(r'C:\xampp\htdocs\cv2\color.png')
```

This would prevent \x in `\xampp` from acting as an escape sequence.

See here for reference: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html

Comment: i did add double \\ but the problem that is the image is NONE and imread cant read color image

Comment: Can you upload and link a sample image?

Comment: did you only replace before x or each of the backslashes?

Comment: each of them img = cv2.imread('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\cv2\\color.png')

Comment: Perhaps you could update your post with the error you get when you run the script in Python now? Your exact code, with the double slashes (or raw string) and sample image, works perfectly for me.